# analyzer and autorelease issues with custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a class that manages the database queries for my project and I'm having some issues with memory management and the `[return autorelease]`part of the code. I don't know how to return an object to the calling function but it uses it afterwards.
The code is this:

```
-(Hexagram *)getHexagramforId:(NSInteger)hexagramNumber{
    Hexagram *current;
    if (init_statement == nil) {
        const char * sql = "SELECT * FROM HEXNUMBER where _id =?";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &init_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error:failed to prepare argument with message %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_bind_int(init_statement, 1, hexagramNumber);
    if (sqlite3_step(init_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        current = [[Hexagram alloc]initWithId:hexagramNumber
                                             Title:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(init_statement, HEX_TITLE)]
                                               LongText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(init_statement, HEX_TEXT)]ShortText:nil InternalColor:sqlite3_column_int(init_statement, INTERNAL_COLOR) ExternalColor:sqlite3_column_int(init_statement, EXTERNAL_COLOR)];

    }else{
        NSAssert1(0, @"Database is corrupt, error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_reset(init_statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
    init_statement = nil;
    return current;
}
return nil;
```

}

So what happens is in the analyzer it says that the object current hexagram is leaked, but if I return it with an autorelease it crashes. I want to support iOS < 5 so I don't want to use ARC but so far I don't know how to return this object and not get this error in the static analyzer. Any help please?

Comment: Are you using ARC in present code?

Comment: Note, you **can** use ARC below iOS 5, but you don't have weak pointers available to you, you only have unsafe_unretained available for non strong types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the reason the analyzer is complaining is because you're creating your `Hexagram` object via `alloc] init`, and returning it like that, which means your object will start out with a retain count of 1. Unless your method names starts with new/alloc/copy, the user of the code (and static analyzer) will be expecting an autoreleased object. (See [documentation of naming conventions + memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)).

As for autorelease; Autorelease will give an object a retain count of 1 (so that it can hang around for a bit), but will be released at the end of a run loop. This will cause a retain count of 0, and the object gets deallocated.

Now, why does `return [current autorelease]` fail? The reason will be because of the caller of the method `getHexagramforId`. If someone is calling a method that returns an autoreleased object (a method that does not start with new/alloc/copy etc...), then it **is their responsibility** to keep hold of that object when it needs to (for the reasons mentioned above).

So for example, if you changed `return current` to `return [current autorelease]`, and called the method as so:

```
Hexagram* obj = [[SomeClass getHexagramforId:3] retain];
```

your program shouldn't crash. You are explicitly retaining an autoreleased object, so you now can keep that object around, until you no longer need it. At that point, call `[obj release]`.

Other methods for retaining an autoreleased object include assigning it to a retaining property, as so:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Hexagram* hexObj;

self.hexObj = [SomeClass getHexagramForId:3];
```

Comment: so is there an alternative to the alloc]init thing? it should be like a class method in the Hexagram class?

Comment: You'd be deferring the `alloc]init`; every object gets created using `alloc]init` at some point in their life, but to abstract that away, some people create class methods to return autoreleased versions. For example `[NSString stringWithString:@"..."]` is the autoreleased version of `[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"..."]`. The autoreleased version will `return [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"..."] autorelease];`

Comment: As such, the method I describe in my answer is the best way. Creating `Hexagram` via `alloc]init` is totally fine, and make sure you return the autoreleased version of it. Then, whatever is using the returned object, make sure they retain it.